# How to encrypt an excel in an InputStream and write to an OutputStream?

Tags: java, excel, encryption, apache-poi

I'm using this within an application where writing to a file is not possible. The data is always in streams. I get the XLSX file in an inputstream and I would like to set a password and write it to an outputstream.

```
public void encrptXslxFile(InputStream inStream, OutputStream outStream){ 
    POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
    EncryptionInfo info = null;
    OutputStream fos;
    OPCPackage opc = null;

    try {
        info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
        Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
        enc.confirmPassword("coffee");
        //inStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\ProjectWork\\Community\\excelfile.xlsx");
        fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
        opc = OPCPackage.open(inStream); //from parameter
        OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
        opc.save(os);
        os.close();

        //fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\ProjectWork\\Community\\excelfilepwd.xlsx");
        //fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
        //fos.close();

        fs.writeFilesystem(outStream); // from parameter
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

While reading from the file and writing to the file, it encrypts fine. But if I use the function and then get the outputstream, and later write it, it creates a zero kb file.
Is this even possible?

I tested with the code below to makes sure the inputstream is good.

```
public void encrptXslxFile(InputStream inStream, OutputStream outStream){     
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(inStream, outStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I was able to write the outputstream to a file.

Comment: How the `encrptXslxFile(InputStream inStream, OutputStream outStream)` gets called? What exact streams are `inStream` and `outStream` then? For me it works when `inStream` is a `FileInputStream` and `outStream` is a `ByteArrayOutputStream` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot create files and POI internally uses files, I had to specifically set the temp directory for POI to use.

```
   TempFile.setTempFileCreationStrategy(new TempFileCreationStrategy() {

        @Override
        public File createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix) throws IOException {
            // check dir exists, make if doesn't
            if(!fileTempDir.exists()){
                fileTempDir.mkdir();
                fileTempDir.deleteOnExit();
            }

            File newFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, fileTempDir);
            return newFile;
        }

        @Override
        public File createTempDirectory(String strPath) throws IOException {
            if(!fileTempDir.exists()){
                fileTempDir.mkdir();
                fileTempDir.deleteOnExit();
                return fileTempDir;
            }else {
                return Files.createTempDirectory(strPath).toFile();
            }
        }
    });
```

This worked for me.